# Advice on Logical Data Tidying for a work project

Tags: r, tidyr

My data set comes from an excel file set up by non-data orientated co-workers. My data is sensitive, so I cannot share the data set, but I will try to make an example so it's easier to see what I'm talking about.  I have a unique identifier column.  My problem is with the date columns.  I have multiple date columns.  When imported into R, some of the columns imported as dates, and some of them imported as excel dates.  then some of the cells in the columns have a string of dates (in character type).  not all the strings are the same size.  Some have a list of 2, some a list 7.

I'm trying to Tidy my data.  My thoughts were to put all the collection dates in one column.  Here is where I'm stuck.  I can use pivot_longer() bc not all the columns are the same type.  I can't convert the excel dates into R dates w/out getting rid of the list of strings. And I can' get rid of the list of strings, bc I'm running into the Error: Incompatible lengths. I think my logic flow is wrong and any advice to point me in the right direction would be helpful.  I can look up coding after i get my flow right.

What I have:

```
  Unique.ID Collection.Date1 Test.Result1 Collection.Date2 Test.Result2        Collection.Date3
1         1       12/12/2020     positive           1/1/21     negative                   44890
2         2         11/30/20     negative   1/8/21,1/20/21     negative 2/10/21,3/10/21,4/10/21
3         3          1/20/21     negative            44011     positive                   44007
4         4          12/1/20     positive            44018     negative                   44064
```

What I would like to have:

```
Unique ID     Collection Date     Test Result

1             12/12/20            positive

1             1/1/21              negative

1             2/2/21              NA

2             11/30/20            negative

2             1/8/21              negative

2             1//20/21            negative

2             2/10/21             NA

2             3/10/21             NA

2             4/10/21             NA

3             1/20/21             negative

3             3/3/21              positive

3             4/3/21              NA

4             12/1/20             positive

4             3/3/21              negative

4             4/3/21              NA
```

If I try to make everything into dates first, it runs into an error bc of the strings.  When I try to expand the strings, since they are different lengths, I get an error doing that.

Comment: try using gather() function in tidyr package

Comment: `pivot_longer()` is the new/improved version of `gather()` in tidyr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't post real data, we have to make some assumptions on the structure of your dataset.

### Data

Assuming, your data looks like

```r
structure(list(Unique.ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4), Collection.Date1 = c("12/12/2020", 
"11/30/20", "1/20/21", "12/1/20"), Test.Result1 = c("positive", 
"negative", "negative", "positive"), Collection.Date2 = c("1/1/21", 
"1/8/21,1/20/21", "44011", "44018"), Test.Result2 = c("negative", 
"negative", "positive", "negative"), Collection.Date3 = c("44890", 
"2/10/21,3/10/21,4/10/21", "44007", "44064")), problems = structure(list(
    row = c(1L, 4L), col = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), expected = c("6 columns", 
    "6 columns"), actual = c("7 columns", "7 columns"), file = c("literal data", 
    "literal data")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(Unique.ID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Collection.Date1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Test.Result1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Collection.Date2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Test.Result2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Collection.Date3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 2L), class = "col_spec"))
```

or for better readability

```r
# A tibble: 4 x 6
  Unique.ID Collection.Date1 Test.Result1 Collection.Date2 Test.Result2 Collection.Date3       
      <dbl> <chr>            <chr>        <chr>            <chr>        <chr>                  
1         1 12/12/2020       positive     1/1/21           negative     44890                  
2         2 11/30/20         negative     1/8/21,1/20/21   negative     2/10/21,3/10/21,4/10/21
3         3 1/20/21          negative     44011            positive     44007                  
4         4 12/1/20          positive     44018            negative     44064
```

Note: This data already doesn't look all too bad. I really can think of much worse data. If your data has some more issues, the following workflow might fail.

### Workflow

I prefer using packages included in `tidyverse`, in this case `dplyr`, `tidyr` and `stringr`.

Based on your data I would perform the following steps:

1. Bringing the data into a long format.
2. Seperate the dates, that are in one cell, namely turning "2/10/21, 3/10/21, 4/10/21" into seperate rows.
3. Bringing the data into a wide format, turning dates and results into a column each.
4. Tidy up your dates, especially taking care of the Excel-style dates.

Turned into code this looks like

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Unique.ID, names_pattern="(.+)(\\d)", names_to=c("name", "no") ) %>%
  mutate(value = str_split(value, ",\\s*")) %>%
  unnest(value) %>%
  pivot_wider(values_fn=list) %>%
  unnest(c(Collection.Date, Test.Result)) %>%
  mutate(Collection.Date = coalesce(as.Date(Collection.Date, "%m/%d/%y"),
                                    as.Date(as.integer(Collection.Date), origin="1900-01-01"))) %>%
  suppressWarnings() %>%
  select(-no)
```

which returns

```r
# A tibble: 15 x 3
   Unique.ID Collection.Date Test.Result
       <dbl> <date>          <chr>      
 1         1 2020-12-12      positive   
 2         1 2021-01-01      negative   
 3         1 2022-11-27      NA         
 4         2 2020-11-30      negative   
 5         2 2021-01-08      negative   
 6         2 2021-01-20      negative   
 7         2 2021-02-10      NA         
 8         2 2021-03-10      NA         
 9         2 2021-04-10      NA         
10         3 2021-01-20      negative   
11         3 2020-07-01      positive   
12         3 2020-06-27      NA         
13         4 2020-12-01      positive   
14         4 2020-07-08      negative   
15         4 2020-08-23      NA
```

Comment: Martin, This is exactly what  i was looking for.  Thank you so much.   This is a much simplified version of my data.  I actually have 8 collection dates, 8 labs, 8 test types, 8 test results, etc columns.  A total of 54 columns.  I'm thinking it's similar to time-series data.  I'm having a little trouble understanding the names_pattern argument and how your mapping specific columns to the new columns.  How are you telling it that all 8 of the collection date columns go to collection date, and all 8 of the test result columns go to test results, and so on.  I have 7 in total to concatenate.

Comment: I found this online as well, which is similar. `df_raw %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(),
  names_to = c("set", ".value"),
  names_pattern = "(.+)_(.+)"
  )`

Comment: It's hard to give an answer without seeing the actual data. The `names_pattern="(.+)(\\d)` looks for any kind of string that ends with a single number and splits that via `names_to=c("name", "no")` two columns: the part in the first `(.+)` goes to "name", the part `(\\d)` goes to "no".

Comment: You can try and run the shown code stepwise and look and the transformations. Probably you can generalize that approach on your real data.

Comment: You are a genius :-)  I now see what is going on.  You put everything into one column, then expanded the lists, then widened it to make multiple columns.  It's getting hung up on the unnest() right now.  The error is:  Error in UseMethod("unnest") no applicable method for 'unnest' applied to an object of class "list".  In addition, 'cols' is now required when using unnest().  I'll start working on getting this working and then use pivot_wider().  Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction!